# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_readytoship'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'readytoship'

Tags: sql-server

Our SQL systems administrator walk out on this issue so it was dumped in my lap. I'm Not a wealth of knowledge on SQL but I get by. He has SQL 2012 ported to SQL2000 server and we got a job query part failing. I pasted the job query into SSMS and got a Violation KEY constraint. Query and error below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```html
INSERT INTO [dbo].[readytoship]
           ([delivery]
           ,[so]
           ,[netvalue]
           ,[createdate]
           ,[resonorder]
           ,[reason]
           ,[shipto]
           ,[insertdate]
           ,[delta]
           ,[shpt])
(select vl06cst.delivery,
vl06cst.salesorder,
netvalue as netvalue,
 createdate,

case when vl06cst.insertdate<maxdte and vl06cst.insertdate>mindte then 'P'
when vl06cst.insertdate=mindte and vl06cst.insertdate<maxdte then 'O'
else 'C' end as resonord,resoncode,

shiptoparty, vl06cst.insertdate, dbo.ElapsedTime(createdate,getdate()) as delta,shippoint
from vl06cst join vbak on right(vbak.salesorder,9)=vl06cst.salesorder join vl06minmaxdte on vl06cst.delivery=vl06minmaxdte.delivery
where isnumeric(vbak.salesorder)>0
group by vl06cst.delivery,vl06cst.salesorder,createdate, resoncode, shiptoparty,vl06cst.insertdate, netvalue,resonorder,mindte,maxdte,shippoint)
Result:
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_readytoship'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'readytoship'.
The statement has been terminated.

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Some sample data and table schemas would go a very long to figuring out the issue, just sayin'

Comment: Someone, for very good reason, has defined a primary key on the target table - your first need to identify what columns they are. Next you need to run your select query on it's own and identify the duplicate rows (where the primary key values appear more than once). Then you need to understand why this is happening in your source data. There is no technical solution to this. You just need to understand your data

Comment: Mark, Nick thanks for your reply. So I need to be looking for a dup ID in the int column and go from there? I get it, I would link some data but not sure how in comments. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You don't put data in the comments. You update your question with that information.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain the integrity of the data, you cannot insert duplicate data into your table, reading your code I believe that you can use this where to solve it.

```
where isnumeric(vbak.salesorder)>0 AND 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[readytoship] A where vl06cst.delivery=A.delivery)
```

You need to understand you your code is trying to insert an existent data on the table readytoship and is this is the best solution

Comment: Very interesting, I'm learning. I'll give that a go, Thanks Mauricio. Much Appreciated.

Comment: Wow It's still executing  Mauricio. Going on 8 minutes.

Comment: You need to check the execution plan and if I suggested the correct key.

Comment: I stopped to check, I think your correct. I'm trying to learn ans I go. What if I RESEED all the tables in the ReadytoShip database? Would that do any good?

Comment: Thanks for all your help yesterday. Got rid of all the dups and reseeded.